# Windows Phone 8 device management

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am asked to come up with a solution for remotely locking and blocking the camera of Windows Phone 8 devices. Also, I have to remotely wipe the data. I am new to Windows Phone development.

In addition, I have to get some device information and send this to a server periodically for tracking purposes.

Could you please provide some inputs?

Comment: You should contact Microsoft if your company is large enough about getting closer integration.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there's no way lock or block the camera on a Windows Phone.

Also, an application can only access its own data, so there's no way to wipe all data on the phone. But you don't need an app for this specific need, as you can already do that using the integrated *Find my phone* service: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/How-to/wp8/basics/find-a-lost-phone

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 also has management functions that can be controlled from a server, one of those functions is to wipe / block the phone. Watch the BUILD videos on Channel 9, its somewhere in there, may have been this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/2-014

Answer (score 0):

I would look into a Mobile Device Management provider such as Silverback (http://silverbackmdm.com/), or Zenprise (http://www.zenprise.com). Microsoft is also releasing an extension to Intune services in 2013 for MDM too.

The MDM providers allow the enforcement of device security policies, including thins such as remote wipe, password enforcement, etc. It's a great way to manage BYOD policies.